# Why didn't Sisko die as forseen at the end of Deep Space Nine?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In [Deep Space Nine](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/star-trek-deep-space-nine-synopsis) - [Episode 4.02 - The Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode)) - we see a 'vision' of Jake in the future saying that Sisko had died. This leaves open a plot question about how this will be fulfilled in the rest of the series.

In the Finale, [What you Leave Behind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind), Sisko joins the wormhole aliens and enters a non-linear existence.

At the end, Sisko experiences the opposite of death - living forever. This contrasts strongly with Jake's vision.

My question is: **Why didn't Sisko die as forseen at the end of Deep Space Nine?**

Comment: Uhm, what?  Didn't Sisko 'die' (get stuck in subspace) in 4.02 because of the Defiant malfunction that was at the start of the episode, and wasn't that future removed, when he avoided the death at the 'end' 4.02 when dodged?

Comment: spoiler in title. Maybe do something like "Vision about Sisko's destiny at the end of DS9" or something. :) idk

Comment: Agree with @Zoredache: I can't find anything in that plot "summary" (it's really a whole-episode recap) to suggest that we see anything from the future which *isn't* in an alternate timeline.

Comment: @Zoredache Re-watch the episode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## He did, from a certain point of view.

Dying and joining the wormhole aliens in an eternal, non-linear existence can both be viewed as the same thing. He is "dead" in that he is no longer living a *mortal* life. It's the sci-fi way of saying "he died and moved on to the afterlife."

> Suddenly finding himself in the Celestial Temple, Sisko is told by Sarah that the Pah Wraiths have been returned to the Fire Caves and will never emerge again. **His task is complete, and it is time for him to rest with the Prophets**. The DS9 crew is puzzled by Sisko's disappearance until he comes to Kasidy in a vision, telling her that **he has moved on to a new stage of his life**. He assures her he will return, but because of his nonlinear nature, it could be in a year, or yesterday.
>
> - [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_You_Leave_Behind)

[image]

---

<sub>As some have pointed out in comments, The episode mentioned in the question, [The Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode)#Summary), is just a self-contained plot that is resolved in that same episode. The possible future in which and elderly Jake says Sisko died is avoided when Sisko dodges the energy discharge that created the loop in the first place.</sub>

> <sub>Ben suddenly finds himself back in the Defiant engine room, just after he saved the ship. **This time he's able to dodge the energy discharge from the warp core.** Jake is puzzled how his dad knew to get out of the way, but Ben, having seen how much his son was willing to give up in order to save him, can only hug him knowing **they now both have a second chance.**</sub>

Comment: Lol for the Ben Kenobi reference. That's awesome!

Comment: True, but this misses the fact that the future Jake in *The Visitor* who said that Ben died will likely never exist, because he managed to prevent the accident that “killed” Ben.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite thanks, I edited my answer accordingly. :)