# How come an older Jadzia Dax appears in DS9 ‘The Visitor’?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, parallel-universe

A UK TV channel has been re-running this here and have just shown an episode, [The Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode)), where Sisko meets a much-older Jake.

Not the most gripping episode, but the future includes an older and noticeably-wrinkly Jadzia.

[image]

But didn't she get killed in a later episode on the main timeline?

Comment: Yes. But as the actress hadn't left at that point it's understandable.

Comment: Which episode are you talking about. For example, most episodes that show us a glimpse of the future end up being an _alternate_ future that ends up never happening. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Visitor_(episode)

Comment: @RedCaio:  I didn't catch the series/episode number or title, but I think Ancalagon has the answer.

Comment: I saw the episode in question the other day (well the end of it) it's the one where a plasma burst from the engine sends sisko jumping forwards in time and jake has to die with him present to snap him back

Comment: If the episode you're talking about is the one @AncalagonTheBlack is describing then he and I are on the same page, as is [Richard's answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/116431/54827)

Comment: Yeah @Richard has the answer I think

Comment: Always in motion, the future is.

Comment: “Not the most gripping episode” — you take that back.

Comment: [Others have been confused by the same issue.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114827/why-didnt-sisko-die-as-forseen-at-the-end-of-deep-space-nine)

Comment: "not the most gripping episode?" - this is a joke, right? It's considered to be one of the best of the series (if not the entire franchise)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The main theme of that episode ([DS9: The Visitor](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/476.htm)) is that Jake's father was trapped in time. By freeing him, Jake caused that particular [timeline](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alternate_timeline) to cease to exist.

> **JAKE SR:** *You see, Melanie, after the last attempt to rescue my father failed, I spent months trying to figure out what went wrong.
>   Eventually, I came to understand the nature of what was happening to
>   him. It was as if he was frozen in time at the moment of the accident,
>   and the link between us was like an elastic cord. Every so often the
>   cord would go taut enough to yank him forward into my time. But only
>   for a few minutes. I realised that if my motion through time came to a
>   stop, the cord would go slack and he'd be lost in subspace forever.
>   But if I could cut the cord when the link was at its strongest, while
>   we were together, he'd return to the moment of the accident.*

Given that Jadzia died as a direct consequence of Ben's ongoing feud with Dukat, it would appear that his disappearance resulted in her not dying in season 6

Comment: Worf must be pretty peeved at Jake for bringing Ben back.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude, unless Sisko specifically asked Jake about this, AND chose to divulge the information to his senior staff, how would word get back to him?

Comment: @Omnidisciplinarianist It wouldn't. It was a joke.